# MySQL Slow union query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT address, min(nm_time) as first, max(nm_time) as last
        FROM (
            (SELECT tx_from as address, nm_time FROM tbl_transactions)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT tx_to as address, nm_time FROM tbl_transactions)
        ) a
        GROUP by address
        ORDER BY first LIMIT 0,10
```

This query takes about 5 seconds to complete (on a fast server)
The table `tbl_transactions` has around 200k records in it. What I'm trying to accomplish is create a list with all unique addresses and their first and last transaction timestamp. I am using pagination, hence the `LIMIT 0,10`.
Any tips how I could improve this?

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table? (tx_to/tx_from/...?)

Comment: No, but indexes on tx_to and tx_from didn't make any difference.

Comment: Please share with us the current indexes, and the explain output. An Index on nm_time is going be important.

Comment: If you want unique addresses, change "union all" to "union".  That might even speed things up.  Also, is it really necessary to query the whole darn table?  Maybe the last x days would be sufficient.

Comment: There is an index on nm_time.

The pagination only shows 10 rows at a time, each page is querying the database again with a new `limit`. Maybe I could improve something here so I don't have to select everything in the union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if either of these will help, but here are two ideas.

One thing to try is doing aggregation in the subqueries:

```
SELECT address, min(minnt) as first, max(maxnt) as last
FROM ((SELECT tx_from as address, min(nm_time) as minnt, max(nm_time) as maxnt
       FROM tbl_transactions
       GROUP BY tx_from
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT tx_to as address, min(nm_time) as minnt, max(nm_time) as maxnt
       FROM tbl_transactions
       GROUP BY tx_to
      )
     ) a
GROUP by address
ORDER BY first
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

One method that can be faster than aggregation is to start with a list of addresses and use correlated subqueries to get the information.  For this to work, you need a table of addresses.  The query would look like:

```
SELECT a.address,
       least((select min(nm_time) from tbl_transactions t where t.tx_from = a.address),
             (select min(nm_time) from tbl_transactions t where t.tx_to = a.address)
            ) as first,
       least((select max(nm_time) from tbl_transactions t where t.tx_from = a.address),
             (select max(nm_time) from tbl_transactions t where t.tx_to = a.address)
            ) as last
FROM addresses a
ORDER BY first
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

This needs two indexes for performance:  `tbl_transactions(tx_from, nm_time)` and `tbl_transactions(tx_to, nm_time)`.

Comment: Your first query was definitely faster, took 2 seconds instead of 5.
Your second query it can't find the table `addresses` because it doesn't exist, how would I do that?
EDIT: nvm I need to learn to read. You've said I needed to create it